# open "chrome://version" page in chrome from command line?

Tags: google-chrome

You can open a URL in chrome from the command line with

`chrome.exe https://google.com`

but when trying to do like `chrome.exe chrome://version`, it simply opens an empty page.

It seems that the chrome protects the privileged pages from abnormal behavior.

Is there any way to open the privileged pages from command line?

Comment: I also tried to do with some command line options like `chrome --no-sandbox chrome://version`, but the results were the same.